# Event Notification on property changed of instantiated object

Tags: c#, oop, networking

Is it possible to create an event handler for an instantiated object for a property change?

EX: I have an online game. There is a class called IOClient which create an instance inside of itself of a Player object that stores the character data once that character logs in.

I want to create an event handler so it would proc whenever that Player objects Map property changes.  (This is mostly to handle map changing, since you can enter different maps using a teleport command or by walking into portals).

Most of the event handling examples for properties must be contained in the same class, but I cannot call the datastream write (as it is part of IOClient)from the Player object, so it cannot work in there.

Changing maps currently looks like this:

```
            case "village":
                player.X = 8;
                player.Y = 12;
                player.Map = "Village";
                SendPacket(new LoadWorld(player, 1).Compile());
                break;
            case "shop1":
                player.X = 8;
                player.Y = 12;
                player.Map = "shop1";
                SendPacket(new LoadWorld(player, 1).Compile());
                npcshop1.SetShop1();
                SendPacket(new CreateNPC(npcshop1).Compile());
                string shopchat = "Gladrial: Click on me to see the menu.";
                SendPacket(new UpdateChatBox(0xff, 0xff, 1, (short)shopchat.Count(), shopchat).Compile());
                break;
```

As you can see everytime a new map loads the NPC/Monster data needs to be sent.  If this case switch was inside an event handler, I can change the map property from different locations, such as a teleport, walking into a portal, a gm teleport without needing to always call the switch case.

Comment: You can create EventHandlers for all kinds of silly stuff. You'll just need to make the object subscribe to it and fire it, when your event happens.

Comment: any link for an example?

Comment: [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ddutta/EventHandlingInNetUsingCS11092005052726AM/EventHandlingInNetUsingCS.aspx) seems suitable.

Comment: Do you mean delegate setting the player.Map property?